# Deploy 2 dependent cloudformation stack parts in 2 regions

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want to deploy 2 cloudformation stack parts in 2 different regions(us-east-1, eu-west-1).

One part creates vpc and x resources - I want deploy to us-east-1.

Second part creates y resources with dependencies to x.Outputs - I want deploy to eu-west-1.

I can't simply run the stack in eu-west-1 region( it will create only the first part)

Any way to do that?

Comment: CFN is regional service. One stack can't reference resources created by a stack in other region.

Comment: If you deploy the stacks programmatically, you can deploy the first one, get its outputs, and pass the outputs as parameters to the second one which you launch in different region.

Comment: how can I use Outputs across regions?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your stacks programmatically, using CLI for example and `bash`, you can do the following (cli example):

1. use [deploy] command to deploy your stack in the first region. CLI has [--region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html) parameter to specify the region for the operation.
2. using basic loop you can wait for the stack to be created. [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) provides status of the stack creation.
3. once the status is `CREATE_COMPLETE` you call [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html)  one more time to get it outputs.
4. you take the outputs from the stack, and deploy the second stack in the region you want. `deploy` command has `--parameter-overrides` which you can specify the input parameters for the second stack. These inputs will be from the outputs you got from the first stack.

You can do similar things using SDK, e.g. boto3 in python.

Comment: Can I do it with cloudformation? get params from Outputs from another region?